# Apache Ignite Data refresh

Tags: caching, ignite

I am using apache ignite to cache my static/reference data from oracle tables.

I have to refresh the data every day at 11:30PM.

**Approach 1**
Using Apache ignite in-built solution, I did not find a way to refresh the data. Please help me if there is any way?

**Approach 2**
I used Quartz API to schedule the job, which is working fine. I am using below steps to reload/refresh the data -

- Stop the Ignite - Ignition.stopAll(true);
- Starting the Ignite - Ignition.start(cfg)
- Load the fresh data - In this step I am getting below exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [igniteInstanceName=null, state=STOPPED]

Could you please help me how to fix or choose the best way to adopt ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can just call `loadCache` method everyday at 11-30. Quartz can be used to schedule that call.

Answer (score 2):

You may also check out built-in scheduler [IgniteScheduler](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cron-based-scheduling)